# Is there a set of integers that will help determine the operators of a function given order of execution, and an output?

Tags: number-theory, functions

Does there exist a set of integers that will reveal operations (only exponents, multiplication, division, addition and, subtraction operators are allowed) used within a function?

For instance, given the function

$f(a, b, c) = a + b * (c / a)$

We adjust for PEMDAS to reveal the true order these variables are referenced

$f(a, b, c) = c / a * b + a$

We have knowledge of the answer when $a, b, c$ have concrete values

$f(a, b, c) = c / a * b + a = D$

We then replace the operators with variables themselves (which we will denote with the @ symbol)

$f(a, b, c) = c @_1 a @_2 b @_3 a = D$

My question is, does there exist a set of numbers that when the first $n$ numbers of said set are used for a function with $n$ parameters, value of the $@$ operation variables are determinable (in the above example $@_1 = /$, $@_2 = *$, and $@_3 = +$) when the knowledge of the output of said function is known along with reference order of the parameters?

Comment: The only operations you allow are the four arithmetic operations? The inputs are integers? reals?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I allow exponents, multiplication, division, addition and, subtraction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the inputs are intended to be a part of this "set of numbers" I'm hoping exists. I'm trying to figure out of there are specific numbers that when passed through a function reveal the functions interior when parameter reference and order of execution is known.

Comment: Sure, but, what kinds of "numbers"? Arbitrary precision reals? Quaternions? Could be important!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand your question and the importance of it now. The supposed set is restricted to integers.

Comment: When you say "is revealed", do you mean that there is a quick way to determine the @'s or just that there exist a unique combination of @'s that give the result?

Comment: @benguin To clarify, I want to determine the @'s